# scala-activerecord: how to pass custom configuration to Tables.initialize?

Tags: scala, activerecord, config, database-schema, typesafe

I want to create tables with scala-activerecord:

```
Tables.initialize(ConfigFactory.load(env))
```

This does not work, because `initialize` accepts only `Map[String, Any]`.
My second try was:

```
Tables.initialize(ConfigFactory.load(env).root())
```

where `root()` returns `ConfigObject`:

```
public interface ConfigObject extends ConfigValue, Map<String, ConfigValue>
```

I still get:

```
Error:(15, 49) type mismatch;
 found   : com.typesafe.config.ConfigObject
 required: Map[String,Any]
  Tables.initialize(ConfigFactory.load(env).root())
                                                ^
```

I don't get it, `Any` should accept any value, why it does not accept `ConfigValue` ?

How can I pass my config to the `Tables.initialize` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I pass my config to the Tables.initialize method?

This might be a solution:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
Tables.initialize(ConfigFactory.load(env).root.unwrapped.toMap)
```

For `ActiveRecordTables#initialize` method, it is assumed that you give the override settings and values as follows:

```
Tables.initialize(Map(
  "driver" -> "org.postgresql.Driver",
  "jdbcurl" -> "jdbc:postgresql://hostname:5432/dbname"
))
```

This feature is supposed to be used for applications such as temporarily overrides the value set (e.g. Coding tests).

https://github.com/aselab/scala-activerecord/blob/281ae4073d1d2f4b04b31520c961f7210c5408d4/activerecord/src/test/scala/samples/AutoDdlSpec.scala#L34

For database settings, please refer to the following:

https://github.com/aselab/scala-activerecord/wiki/Database-Settings